# Interactive QSqlTableModel

Tags: sql, qt, qtableview

Please could you give me an advice. I am using QSqlTableModel class to access the database table and QTableView to view it. What signal of what instance should I handle to know about user move the cursor in QTableView?

I want to update the content of TableView B after the cursor moved in QTableView A (Table B have foreign keys to table A in database)

May be somewhat from this http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ivan, if you are talking about table cursor, you can reimplement [QAbstractItemView::moveCursor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#moveCursor) method which is virtual.

If you're talking about mouse cursor, you can use [QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#viewportEvent) method to detect mouse move event. You need to set QWidget::setMouseTracking(true) to the viewport of your QTableView.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks! I am talking about QAbstractItemView::moveCursor. You have helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using the [selection model](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-in-item-views)

> **Using a selection model**
>
> The standard
>   view classes provide default selection
>   models that can be used in most
>   applications. A selection model
>   belonging to one view can be obtained
>   using the view's `selectionModel()`
>   function, and shared between many
>   views with `setSelectionModel()`, so the
>   construction of new selection models
>   is generally not required.

If you have an **shared selection model** the views will be updated not matter which one changes. You can then react to it. The [selection flags](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qitemselectionmodel.html#SelectionFlag-enum) control if you want a cell, row or multiple selections.

See also [working with selections](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/modelview.html#3-2-working-with-selections) :

```
//selection changes shall trigger a slot
     QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel= treeView->selectionModel();
     connect(selectionModel, SIGNAL(selectionChanged (const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)),
             this, SLOT(selectionChangedSlot(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)));
 }
```